# Nonsense change of floor and enemies materials (when restarting scene)

Tags: unity

**I have a game where:**

- player (green cube)
- enemies (red cubes)
- floor (blue plane)

**Image before losing (player colliding with enemy):**

[image]

**Image after restarting game:**

[image]

**GameOver Code (Player.cs):**

```
void Update () {
    if(!gameOver){
        move();
    }else{
        if(Input.GetKey("space")){
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Cena1");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj){
    if(obj.gameObject.tag=="Inimigo"){
        canvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        gameOver=true;
    }       
}
```

The problem happens every time I collide the player with the enemy and press the spacebar to restart the scene.

The same thing happens if I use: `SceneManager.LoadScene("Cena1");`.

---

**EDIT 1 (Added full scripts)**

**script_Player.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class script_Player : MonoBehaviour {

    private float speed=0.4f;
    private float x,y,z,iniX,iniY,iniZ;
    private GameObject canvas;
    private bool gameOver=false;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        canvas=GameObject.Find("Canvas");
        canvas.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        iniX=transform.position.x;
        iniY=transform.position.y;
        iniZ=transform.position.z;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(!gameOver){
            move();
        }else{
            if(Input.GetKey("space")){
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Cena1");
            }
        }

        getPositions();

        parede();

    }

    void move(){
        if(Input.GetKey("w")){
            transform.position+=new Vector3(0,0,speed);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("s") && transform.position.z>-10){
            transform.position+=new Vector3(0,0,-speed);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("a") && transform.position.x>-4.25){
            transform.position+=new Vector3(-speed,0,0);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("d") && transform.position.x<4.25){
            transform.position+=new Vector3(speed,0,0);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("space")){
            //transform.position+=new Vector3(0,0.3f,0);
            rb.AddForce(0,100,0);
        }
    }

    void getPositions(){
        x=transform.position.x;
        y=transform.position.y;
        z=transform.position.z;
    }

    void parede(){
        if(transform.position.x<-4.25){
            transform.position=new Vector3(-4.25f,y,z);
        }
        if(transform.position.x>4.25){
            transform.position=new Vector3(4.25f,y,z);
        }
        if(transform.position.z<-10){
            transform.position=new Vector3(x,y,-10);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj){
        if(obj.gameObject.tag=="Inimigo"){
            //Destroy(obj.gameObject);
            //SceneManager.LoadScene("Cena1");
            canvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            gameOver=true;
        }       
    }
}
```

**script_Inimigo.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class script_Inimigo : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool left=false,right=false;
    public float speed=0.08f;
    private float x,y,z,y2;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        z=transform.position.z;
        left=true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        GameObject player=GameObject.Find("Player");
        y2=player.transform.position.y;

        x=transform.position.x;
        transform.position=new Vector3(x,y2,z);

        if(left){
            transform.position+=new Vector3(-speed,0,0);
            if(transform.position.x<-4.25){
                left=false;
                right=true;
            }
        }else if(right){
            transform.position+=new Vector3(speed,0,0);
            if(transform.position.x>4.25){
                right=false;
                left=true;
            }
        }

        if(z+3<player.transform.position.z){
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a new empty project that includes only these scripts shown here? If not, then there's a good chance there's a relevant detail you haven't recorded for us to work with.

Comment: @DMGregory I created a new project and this time when I die, only the floor material is removed. I added the full scripts to the question.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso Have you verified that the materials are actually changing in the inspector window? I suspect this is actually a problem with automatically-generated lighting. As a quick test to see if this is the case, un-tick "Auto-Generate" in the [lighting window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GlobalIllumination.html) and hit "Generate Lighting" automatically.

Comment: This looks like a lighting issue. Are you using static/realtime light baking? If yes, try disabling both of them and bake. That should clear all old lighting data.

Comment: @Chaosed0 It worked with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have a strange change in your scene, remember to verify your lighting settings. In this case, the problem is caused by the "Auto-generate Lighting" setting within the Unity [lighting window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GlobalIllumination.html) being checked. If you manually generate the lighting by un-checking this option and hitting "Generate", then the problem should go away.

Note that lighting changing with in the editor when a scene changes is a [persistent](https://answers.unity.com/questions/919940/applicationloadlevel-changes-lighting-for-some-rea.html) and [common](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1370782/lighting-is-different-after-changing-ascne.html) issue.